# Is taking screenshot every few seconds in the background a good idea

Tags: android

I'm trying to screenshare my android phone to a web app. I take screenshot every few seconds using the method shown in code. I convert the screenshot image to Base64 and pass it as string to a web service. The web app displays the image and everything works fine

I use `Service` and `TimerTask` to take screenshot. Thiss is the code to take screenshot.

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor();
```

I want to know if this will cause any problems to the phone because I did this and after a while the phone turned off and wouldn't turn on for a while. I dont know if my app caused it or if it was something else

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if this will cause any problems to the phone because I did this and after a while the phone turned off and wouldn't turn on for a while.

**I don't think your app caused this. Try on some other phones, if you notice same behaviour then it is your app.**

Why do you need `su` permission to take screenshots? I hope you do realise that if you ask for `su` permission, your code won't work on non-rooted phones. There are other methods to take screenshots without requiring root permissions.

Secondly, do you externally inform user that your app will take screenshots from time to time? If no; then you are invading privacy.

Comment: Yeah, I feel that such behavior is either malicious, or is made for monitoring purposes, either way it IS a huge privacy invasion. Not to mention that the his application can potentially fill up the SD card of the user with a ton of useless screen shots.

Comment: @gedo I'm trying to do this for providing support to a client..and I'm giving the same name for every screenshot. so there's only one image that keeps getting replaced

Comment: @boo support to a client means you have a client and you are providing support to them? or Is this an app that is designed to do so?

Comment: @boo ok cool. Then make sure they have su permissions. As i said the phone turn off problem should not happen. It might be some other problem on your device, try to test it on some other phones.